# Use Screenflow to change record type

Tags: visual-workflow, record-type, sharing-rule, setup, user-profile

Can someone help us with this issue?

We have two record types for the account object; Vendor and Resident. The sharing rule on the Account object is set to Public Read only. Now, a user with a custom Sales User profile is reporting that an account record with the wrong record type. We originally assigned the Vendor record type to the Sales user profile.

But we are trying to use a screen flow to change the record type for them, just to automate things. Will this affect the sales users record access in any way once we activate and run the flow? So, we don’t end up creating another avoidable crisis.

Will the record  Read access be lost?
Will the record access remains the same?
Will the record edit access be lost?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Enoch, thanks for posting. I've just got a couple of questions to clarify to help answer your question. Does your sharing rule on Account use the Record Type in it's criteria? Also, when you say you're creating a screen flow, is that for you as an administrator to use or for your users?

Answer (score 0):

Since the access for your Account object is set to Public, all users can access all record types, no matter which profile they have.
The assigned record types on a profile only determine which record types are available when users with this profile create records for the object, but they will always have access to all of them.

Comment: To be pedantic, you can only set a record type you have access to, including changing on an edit.